# Eliminar un elemento puntual en un Array

Tags: javascript, angular

primero que nada gracias si te tomaste tiempo de darme una mano.
Tengo un carrito de compras en el que agrego productos; tengo una pagina con el detalle de los productos agregados al carrito en filas, es decir una fila por cada producto, y al lado una columna de acciones para agregar y quitar productos que ya fueron seleccionados y que ya se encuentran en el carrito de compras. conseguí agregar productos, pero no consigo eliminarlos, o sea, no consigo eliminar un producto en particular. me podrías ayudar?

Modelo

```
export interface Product {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  price: number;
  description: string;
  image: string;
}
```

HTML

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper>
<mat-step>
<ng-template matStepLabel>Sus Productos</ng-template>
<div *ngIf="(products$ | async | countProduct) as products"> 
<p *ngIf="products.length === 0">
No hay productos en el carrito
</p>
<div class="row" *ngFor="let product of products">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-ms-2 col-md-2">
<div class="box">
{{ product.title }}
<img class="image" [src]="product.image" alt="">
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-ms-2 col-md-2">
<div class="box">
<p>Cantidad</p>
{{ product.cantidad }}
</div>
</div> 
<div class="col-xs-12 col-ms-2 col-md-2">
<div class="box">
<p>Precio unidad</p>
{{ product.price | currency}}
</div>
</div> 
<div class="col-xs-12 col-ms-2 col-md-2">
<div class="box">
<button mat-raised-button color="prmary" (click)="addProduct(product)">
+
</button>
<button mat-raised-button color="prmary" (click)="deleteProduct(product)">
-
</button>
</div>
</div> 
</div>
<button mat-raised-button color="primary" matStepperNext 
[disabled]="products.length === 0">Siguiente</button>
</div>
</mat-step>
<mat-step>
<ng-template matStepLabel>Datos Personales</ng-template>
<app-customer-data></app-customer-data>
</mat-step>
<mat-step>
<ng-template matStepLabel>Pago</ng-template>
<h1>pago</h1>
</mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Servicio

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Product } from './../models/product.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CartService {

private products: Product[] = []; 
private cart = new BehaviorSubject<Product[]>([]);
cart$ = this.cart.asObservable();

constructor() { }

addCart(product: Product) { 
this.products = [...this.products, product]; 
this.cart.next(this.products); 
}

deleteCart(product: Product) {
const eliminar = this.products.findIndex(p => p.id === product.id);
this.products = [...this.products.splice(eliminar), product];
this.cart.next(this.products);
}
}
```

Componente

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Product } from './../../../core/models/product.model';
import { CartService } from './../../../core/services/cart.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-order',
  templateUrl: './order.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./order.component.scss']
})
export class OrderComponent implements OnInit {

products$: Observable<Product[]>; 

constructor(
private cartService: CartService 
){
this.products$ = this.cartService.cart$; 

}

addProduct(product: Product) {
this.cartService.addCart(product);
}

deleteProduct(product: Product) {
this.cartService.deleteCart(product);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
}
}
```

Comment: Por favor, no publiques imagenes con código, publica el código mismo (como texto).

Comment: Lo primero seria copiar el codigo que tienes y ponerlo en la pregunta, pues como ha dicho el usuario @jachguate el codigo no debe estar en imagenes segun lineamientos de la comunidad, leer [ask], lo segundo es que el componente no nos aporta tanta informacion en este caso como nos lo podria aportar el `HTML` en si, en tu caso solo nos muestras 2 botones que se encargan de agregar y eliminar, pero como muestras esos elementos?, esa es la duda mas grande, por que si es por medio de un `*ngFor` angular tiene una peculiaridad que tendria que explicarte.

Comment: Sin embargo se agradece que pongas el codigo de tu componente para poder vizualizar mejor el problema, si editas tu codigo y lo pones como texto no te olvides de agregar esa informacion.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, no sabía que no podía subir una imagen del código, lo reemplazaré y agregaré más información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está en la siguiente línea `this.products =[...this.products.splice(eliminar), product];`.

Estas añadiendo otra vez el producto borrado con el `splice`. La variable `product` no hace falta que la vuelves a añadir en el array.
Debería ser así `this.products = [...this.products.splice(eliminar)];`

Otro error es que el `splice` no te devuelve un nuevo array con los nuevos elementos sino que modifica el array original que tiene y devuelve los elementos borrado. Por lo tanto, el spread que haces `[...this.products.splice(eliminar)];` no es correcto.

La solución sería así.

```
deleteCart(product: Product) {
  const eliminar = this.products.findIndex(p => p.id === product.id); 
  this.products.splice(eliminar, 1);
  // si quieres crear un array nuevo puedes hacer lo siguiente
  // this.products = [...this.products];
  
  this.cart.next(this.products);
}
```

Comment: Muchas pero muchas gracias! funcionó! gracias por tomarte el tiempo de ayudarme.

Answer (score 2):

Usa el metodo `findIndex()` al cual de pasas un método para validar la igual del objecto,
`p = producto` , si el producto es distinto puedes tambien usar `p.id = producto.id`.

```js
let productos = []
let producto = { id: 441 }
let producto1 = { id: 442 }
let producto2 = { id: 443 }

// agrega los 3 productos
productos.push(producto)
productos.push(producto1)
productos.push(producto2)

// busca el indice del objeto a eliminar
let eliminar = productos.findIndex( p => p == producto)
// se eliminar lo contenido en el indice
productos.splice(eliminar,1);

console.log(productos)
```

Comment: Hola Diego, muchas gracias por tu tiempo, sigo sin poder eliminar un producto solo, modifiqué el código pero no me da el resultado esperado.